# Hazelcast Topic order issue each 100K events

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am checking the throughput of hazelcast cluster with different number of Topic publishers and subscribers. 
With 2 publishers and 2 subscribers everything works ok.
With 3 publishers and 1 subscriber I found an order issue:
Each 100K events for each publisher I have order mismatch of 2 - 10 events.
Hazelcast version: 3.6.1

Here is my config:

```
@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    Config config = new Config();
    config.getGroupConfig().setName("test").setPassword("test");
    config.setTopicConfigs(getTopicConfigs());
    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}

private Map<String, TopicConfig> getTopicConfigs() {
    TopicConfig topicConfig = new TopicConfig(topicName);
    topicConfig.setStatisticsEnabled(false);
    return new HashMap<String, TopicConfig>(){{put(topicName,topicConfig);}};
}

@Profile("out")
@Bean
public ITopic<Event> eventsOutput(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
    return hazelcastInstance.getTopic("events");
}

@Profile("in")
@Bean
public ITopic<Event> eventsInput(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
    return hazelcastInstance.getTopic("events");
}
```

Here is some part of the logs:

```
Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 200001 != 200000 (expected)
Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 200002 != 200001 (expected)
Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 200003 != 200002 (expected)
Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 200000 != 200003 (expected)

Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 300001 != 300000 (expected)
Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 300002 != 300001 (expected)
Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 300003 != 300002 (expected)
Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 300004 != 300003 (expected)
Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 300005 != 300004 (expected)
Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 300006 != 300005 (expected)
Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 300000 != 300006 (expected)

Not matched for publisher3, seq numbers: (current) 100001 != 100000 (expected)
Not matched for publisher3, seq numbers: (current) 100002 != 100001 (expected)
Not matched for publisher3, seq numbers: (current) 100003 != 100002 (expected)
Not matched for publisher3, seq numbers: (current) 100000 != 100003 (expected)

Not matched for publisher2, seq numbers: (current) 500001 != 500000 (expected)
Not matched for publisher2, seq numbers: (current) 500000 != 500001 (expected)

Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 400001 != 400000 (expected)
Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 400002 != 400001 (expected)
Not matched for publisher1, seq numbers: (current) 400000 != 400002 (expected)
```

etc...

I could think that the issue is inside my code. But :
- the test code is very simple without any additional process
- seq numbers of order mismatch are very pretty and repeatable
- issue is reproduced only when number of publishers increased from 2 to 3.

So I suppose the issue is with hazelcast config. Looks like I missed something. I am rereading hazelcast specification, trying some properties but unsuccessfully.
Could somebody please give a prompt what can be the source of this issue?

Will appreciate any notes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: for the sake of test: can you try to pass this `-Dhazelcast.event.sync.frequency=2147483647` (=max int) when starting your JVM?

Comment: Jaromir, Thank you. This is the right answer. This property is the reason of this issue. The value of this property is separate question: I will not set it to max integer because of memory and network issues in this case. Value of this property depends on project requirements. And interesting that this property is not described in the spec. I found it (with your note) only in sources. Please formalize your comment as "official" answer.